# Minecraft 15w37a: Pistons not being pushed

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I'm trying to make a bank for a "minecraft city." I use this technique that ACtennisAC used:

The pistons are to "automatically" push the minecarts. However, whatever in any way, the pistons are not doing anything whatsoever, they're OFF. I'm trying with a redstone loop so that pistons do not get results that they're STUCK, so the other minecarts are NOT moving whatsoever at that result.

Please help!

Comment: Hard to understand what your problem is; a screenshot of the setup you have would be useful. It doesn't seem as though any pistons are being used in the video you have linked.

Comment: @colorfusion He can't post images or links yet. **Remember, reputation restrictions!** (Also "www.google.com" is not a link, but "[www.google.com](http://www.google.com)" is a link.)

Comment: @aytimothy I've definitely seen new users post links before; I think there's a limit of two per post.

Comment: A + B = C, A2 + B2 = C2

Comment: Are you able to have activator rails in front so that when a minecart is placed, the pistons are activated?  You could also put a redstone torch next to a powered rail so that it is activated.  Place a block in the place that you do not wish the cart to go.

Comment: @Star OS What should these equations tell us? I only know that at least one of the variables must = 0